# Is there a way to implement a IntRangeField in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

all ! Here's my dreadful case, thank you for helping out!
I want to have a document like this:

```
<doc>
    ...
    <arr name="occupiedDays"> -- multivalued range field
         <range>1 TO 10</range>
         <range>5 TO 15</range>
    </arr>
    ...
</doc>
```

And the reason why I want to do this is because it's so much lighter than having all the numbers in there, of course.
Just to be clear, I want to avoid having this in solr:

```
<doc>
    ...
    <arr name="occupiedDays"> -- multivalued int field
         <str>1</str>
         <str>2</str>
         <str>3</str>
         <str>4</str>
         <str>5</str>
         <str>6</str>
         <str>7</str>
         <str>8</str>
         <str>9</str>
         <str>10</str>
    </arr>
    ...
</doc>
```

And then perform range queries on this range field like: fq=-occupiedDays:[5 TO 30]

Anybody has any idea? I have asked and searched all over the internet and seems solr does not support this.

Any help would be really helpful! Thanks in advanced.

Federico

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: Because it's huge and makes my document much more heavier than it should be. Lets say I have a range from 1 to 100, it's better if I could just have it in one value rather than in 100 right?

Comment: It seems like it would be better to use the [`fl` parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) to specify that you don't want/need the value of `occupiedDays`  in the result.

Comment: But it would still be really heavy on the index, It's not a matter of being slow on the response but when I try to store a really big big range solr throws an OutOfMemory error even though it has 1024M of ram assignated to it. So this is why i'm trying to lower the size of the document being submitted

Comment: I see. Store a `start` and an `end`? Then query on `start:[5 TO *] AND end:[* TO 30]` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, do you mind showing me with an example of how the xml of tha would look like? Thank you a lot for your guidance and help.

Comment: In the result: `<field name="start">5</field><field name="end">30</field>`

Comment: Oh no, my ranges are not contiguous. 

I could have ranges like this: 

1 TO 15 
5 TO 30 
50 TO 60 

And so on... I'm not sure that what you supposed would work, right?

Comment: I suspect that you'd have to implement your own [custom field type](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/FieldType.html).

Comment: Yeah, I've read this: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Creating-a-new-field-type-td494280.html in order to do that. But how would I get into solr and tell it how that field should work ? I've got no idea hehe

Comment: Solr is open source, so you can [download the source](http://apache.dataphone.se/lucene/solr/3.5.0/apache-solr-3.5.0-src.tgz) and use the existing fields as an example. Once you've made your field type, you'd pack it in a `jar` and place it in the solr `lib` directory.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thanks a lot. Even though I wonder how solr doesn't support such an easy feature...

Comment: If you end up producing a working model, consider creating an issue on the [Solr JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR) or posting the field here for others.

Comment: That's if I ever got to solve it! So far I haven't even found a single example of how to do this or guidance anywhere! We shall see :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have many choices:

- either you need this field for **searching**, and in this case the mapping needs to be explicit (Lucene/Solr is an **inverted** index, meaning that for every single field instance, it stores the list of documents which contain this field instance),
- either you only need this field to be **stored**, and in that case my best advice would be to store it outside of Solr.

The name of your field makes me think that you are working on some availability system. You might be interested in this question:

- [SOLR travel site: on date queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118177/solr-travel-site-on-date-queries)

Comment: I need this field for searching! And indeed is similar to the problem posted on the link you shared with me. But I have no idea and I haven't found much documentation of how to implement a new FieldType on Solr and deploy it. I have also posted the same question here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-IntRangeField-in-Solr-td3782083.html

Comment: All you need to do is to write a class that extends FieldType http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/FieldType.html and then declare it in your schema.xml (<fieldType name="myFieldType" class="MyFieldType.class" />) and use your fieldType definition for some field (<field name="myField" type="myFieldType" />). Your MyFieldType class needs to be packed in a Jar in the lib directory of your core (or in sharedLib if you are using a multicore setup).

Comment: That's fair and I know how to pull that one, but how can I let Solr know how that class should filter ?

Comment: You need to override getFieldQuery and getRangeQuery depending on whether you are filtering on a single value or on a range.

Comment: And that's it? I can't believe it's that easy :|. I'll give it a try though!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you preprocess your data into buckets and only submit the final results to SOLR. Define a fixed number of buckets, incremented 10 at a time plus one additional bucket for numbers beyond that range. For instance, you could have 3 buckets of 10 which would be 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 and one for 31 or more. Then, either count records into each bucket by incrementing the bucket by one for each record where the ocuppiedDays falls into the bucket, or sum up the days, by adding the occupiedDays of each record into the appropriate bucket. Depends on what you want to do with the data, and the right solution might even be to do it both ways in separate fields.

By the way, 1024M of RAM is not very much to give a large SOLR database. Normally SOLR stores the entire index in RAM, and when you do search queries it also caches a copy of the result set in RAM which includes any non-indexed fields in the result set. Check the caching configuration in solrconfig.xml because you may be caching too much data. Also, if you have a lot of unindexed fields, consider placing that info in a separate key-value store so that they don't take up RAM for caching.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your solution, preprocess my data into buckets how ? Thanks for replying! Also, my solr DB is not very big actually, right now it's holding 4/5k documents which are not precisely big, and it only throws OOM when trying to submit a document with a very wide ranges.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand how this approach might work.  Could I have buckets from 23423-9999 ? Because those numbers that you see are days so I would enter them in solr like this:

20120311
20120312
...

Comment: Your example showed numbers 1 TO 10 and 5 TO 15. If your examples are not correct then people will not understand your question.