# Is it possible (or wise) to use Solr for a reservation system?

Tags: solr

I am relatively new to Solr and need help to decide whether it is the right tool (and if it is, how it should be used) for my task.

I have a use-case where there are some entities with a number of resource types, and the users need to find the entities with enough free resources. To make it less abstract, lets say there are several car-rental companies, and several car types (SUV, microbus, truck...); we track for each company/car type/day combination the number of cars available. The user wants to rent some number of cars for a given time span, and we need to find out which companies could fulfill that request.

There are other aspects of the search, for which Solr seems a good match (each entity has a number of properties, think company location, price, existence of green rental policy etc, and those need to be searchable, with range filters and faceted search, and sorted based on user feedback scores), so it would be nice if the resource allocation aspect could be shoehorned into Solr.  Is that possible? Is it a bad idea for some reason? Can you maybe recommend a tool which is better suited for the task?

---

After browsing the Solr docs, I came up with this scheme:

- the companies are the documents
- each day/car-type combination is a dynamic field which holds the number of free cars of the given type, on the given day at that company
- the condition then will be a huge boolean expression consisting of terms like `field_<car_type>_<day>:[<required_number> TO *]`

I am uncertain about it for several reasons:

- it would require thousands of fields - could that cause performance problems?
- as I understand it, Solr unpacks range queries into lots of equality checks OR-ed together, so the queries will end up having thousands of terms - again, could that cause performance problems?
- the field values would change every time users make reservations - as I understand, that would force a reindexing, which is slow, so same question as above.

I would appreciate any pointers on how to handle this problem (e.g. some other search tool to use, or how Solr could interact with some custom code that did the reservation checks).

Comment: Couldn't you just use good old SQL for most of your work, and having a Solr index fine tuned for searching, where you can merge together fields, and so on. You should be able to import the data from SQL to solr using http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler

Comment: @rcomblen I could use SQL to check availability, though I would prefer not to run complicated SQL queries on every search request. What I don't see is how to integrate it with Solr. I would either need to run an SQL query to get the list of companies with enough resources, and then feed that list to Solr (I'm not sure how to do that), or run the Solr search first, and filter out the unavailable cars with SQL (that would mess up Solr data like paging and facet counts). On first glance, your link seems to be about importing documents from SQL, not importing the results of a per-query filter.

Comment: A similar question: [SOLR travel site: on date queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118177/solr-travel-site-on-date-queries)

Answer (score 2):

Your problems seem to be similar to those faced in Hotel industry and in Shopping industry. You may find [the presentation from Gilt](http://www.slideshare.net/trenaman/personalized-search-on-the-largest-flash-sale-site-in-america) helpful.

The basic sentiment seems to be that you may need to redefine your *document* to be something more fine-grained than your original idea. In your case, this might be indexing *availability* as Solr *document*, with additional information either replicated for each availability slot or using [Solr join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) operator.

Comment: Thanks! The slides are very interesting, and using every company/day/type triplet as a document seems like a good idea. What I don't get about the Gilt presentation though is how they factor in availability. The slides just say they have a custom filter (I assume that means a Solr plugin written in Java), which contacts the inventory service. Does that mean a call to an external service for every result of a search? (The example code seems to suggest so.) That sounds horribly expensive.

Comment: The join operator is also interesting, but if I understand it correctly, it just means that you can filter on shared data (which is a field of the company, not the company/type/day), but you only get the child data back in the end (e.g. you can show a result list with available cars from companies located in Chicago, but you can't show for each result item where that company is located). Doesn't that cripple the whole thing?

Comment: Join operator is an early stage thing and could be not-perfect fit. There is some work on parent/child indexing together. Check solr-user mailing list for multiple discussions on this.

The custom filter does not have to be terribly expensive if done right. You can probably cache for a short period of time, collocate services, etc. Solr gives you lifecycle hooks that may help. Also, you might be able to reach Gilt guys with very specific question you have on that presentation. And somehow it works for them (with very high traffic), so there must be a way.